# Local development and remote deploying in GCP/JupyterHub

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, jupyterhub

I have a multi-user JupyterHub instance deployed in a VM in GCP. I'm trying to find a way to have local development of the source code and remote deploying in the VM, since the JupyterHub is multi-user but single-instance, thus preventing remote development by several users.

Is this even possible, or should I approach this in another way?

Answer (score 1):

For [JupyterHub](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/google.html), I think the best way to "deploy" code that's being developed and tested locally, you can use git (e.g. GitHub) to create a local repository and later you can push the content of that local repository to a remote repository. With this, every user (on their own personal computer) can make their own contributions and later on JupyterHub you can download the result of that from the remote repository using the terminal.

You can open a terminal like this:

[image]

And from there clone/pull the changes from the remote repository, like this:

```
jupyter-username@instance-name:~$ git clone https://github.com/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures.git
```

This approach also works within the instance, every user can do changes within the local repository located in the instance (each user will have an individual local repository) and later they can push & pull their changes to the remote repository so their work keeps on sync.

**Edit:**

Complementing my answer, the first scenario described is with every collaborator with a local repository on their own personal computer (which I think is what you refer by local on the question), that way they'll have their own working space and won't have access to every other user repository. If you want to separate even further the repositories, you can take a look at how [forking projects](https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/) works, so every collaborator can have a fork of the main project and later when anyone wants to add their changes they can make a pull-request.

Finally, I think you'll find useful the following links for deploying using git [link1](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa) & [link2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks), and for more on pull requests see [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request), for [merging](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.13/user/articles/merging-a-pull-request) and for permissions on [user account repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository) and for [organizations](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization).

Comment: That is what I was trying to avoid, having several individual repositories stored in the VM. Specially regarding every user having access to every other user repository. I really wanted a way to work on my local machine and then just deploy and run in the VM.

Comment: @RuiBastos I've edited a bit my answer to make it more clear, also added some additional references that you can consider to work with JupyterHub & git for deploy.

Comment: Still doesn't do what I want. Maybe my question isn't clear and I should edit it? I guess what I wanted was to have a way to use the Python installed in the VM as a kernel for my local dev project. If I clone the repository to the VM, everyone with access will be able to edit and push through that, possibly loosing traceability.

Comment: @RuiBastos What you have on the VM and the actual repositories are two different things, the access level will be set by you, if you don't want your collaborators to have the final word on what's pushed to the main repository, you can ask them to use a fork as I mentioned on the answer, and limit their access on the main repository, they should not have permissions to push changes. I'm adding a few links to my answer so you see how pull requests work and the permission levels for git. I suggest you to follow the links and read about it, many open source projects work like this.

Comment: @RuiBastos After re-reading your last comment, I think you want to work locally with your notebook to add code and make changes (no local execution), and run it on the JupyterHub, I think I've seen that approach before, but that's something different, usually for that you need to keep a SSH connection open between your local environment and Jupyter, not sure if that will work with JupyterHub, but I've seen it with JupyterLab, here you can see how it works https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/ssh-access I suggest you to take a look at the local port forwarding link.